# How to set schedule to run a certain file at a certain timing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-cron, node-schedule

I want to try run this file on command prompt at 10am everyday, but this code does not seem to be working.

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");
var dailyJob = schedule.scheduleJob("0 0 10 * *", function() {
   console.log("Its connecting to database....");
});
dailyJob.start();
```

Comment: Is your script actually running at 10am? This will not register a cron job in the system. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: nope, its not running.. theres no error message as well

Comment: If your script is not running, the scheduler cannot execute the job. I added an answer for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how the scheduler works. The scheduler will only work as long as your script is running. If you stop your script, the scheduler will not work. So if your script is not running at 10am, it will not execute your function.

If you want a script to be executed without your script running you need register a cronjob in the system.

For Linux, you create a `script.js` file, then call `crontab -e` to add a cronjob with this line:

```
0 10 * * * node /path/to/script.js
```

This will run your script every day at 10am. See [this wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) on stackoverflow for more information.

Comment: can i also ask if my computer is in sleep mode, will it still run at 10am during the weekends when im not in sch?

Comment: @KohShuanJin No, your computer has to be running to execute the script. Otherwise you need another computer (a server) to run your script.

Comment: If I use cronjob what is the point of using "node-cron" then ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to have the script running in the background or make it as a service.

## Step 1: Make a schedule script

There are [many packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cron) for scheduling, most are cron based.

This is a sample with `cron` package,

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second', Date.now());
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

When you run this, does it log a new line every second?

[image]

Great!

## Step 2: Make it run on background

So how can you run it on background or as a service? There are lots of options here too, `forever`, `pm2`, `systemctl` etc. I'll use `pm2`.

Go over and install `pm2`,

```
npm i -g pm2
```

Start the script you want to run on background,

```
pm2 start index.js --name=run-every-second
```

Check the logs,

```
pm2 logs run-every-second
```

And it will continue to run on background,

[image]

You can even make it run on startup and so on using,

```
pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

Peace!

Comment: yes, it does.. but however, how how do i let the program type in "node testing.js" by itself in the command prompt. It is requested by my teacher that the program will run by itself whenever the time is up.

Comment: Something still has to run and wait for the time, right? All my answer above was for nodeJS and not for the operating system. There are several ways to resolve this however I need to know which OS you use and a bit more details about your problem.